# Full height map with fixed height header and footer and sidebar issue

Tags: html, css, google-maps

Trying to achieve the layout as demostrated in the image. This is achieved by the working code below. Is this the best solution or are there other reliable alternatives that will produce the same layout?

http://i50.photobucket.com/albums/f337/TheHoplite/layout.png

The problem is making the sidebar content SCROLLABLE as overflow:auto and overflow:scroll do not appear to be working?

CSS

```
    html { overflow: hidden;}

    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
        color: white;
    }

    #header, #footer, #left
    {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
    }

    #header 
    {
        top: 0;
        height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #footer
    {
        bottom: 0;
        height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #left
    {
        top: 50px;
        bottom: 50px;
        width: 250px;

        overflow: auto;

        padding-bottom: 20px;

        text-align: center;
    }

    #mapcontainer 
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50px;
        bottom: 50px;
        left: 250px;
        right: 0;
    }

</style>
```

HTML

```
     <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false">
    </script>

</head>

<body onload="initialise();">

    <div id="header" style="background-color: black;">HEADER</div>

    <div id="container" style="background-color: yellow;">
        <div id="left" style="background-color: red;">SIDEBAR SCROLLABLE</div>
        <div id="mapcontainer" style="background-color: blue;">MAP</div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer" style="background-color: black">FOOTER<br></br></div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialise() {


            var myPos = new google.maps.LatLng(51 , 0);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 3,
                center: myPos,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcontainer"),myOptions);
        }


    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Don't use absolute positioning. Use FLOATS. See: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/

Comment: Have tried with floats, google maps div seems to have problems staying at 100% of the container and becomes larger than the browser

Comment: You're probably not clearing your floats. Absolute positioning for ENTIRE layouts is a poor practice.

Comment: @diodeus I'm clearing the floats but when you use google maps in a div, the map ends up with the height of the whole window not the height of the div its actually in. Float Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zGYft/

Comment: I don't have an issue with your layout posted above. The left box is scrolling with long enough content (i.e. your `overflow: auto` seems to work fine). Personally, I disagree with Diodeus. I think whether an entire layout should be absolutely positioned or not depends solely on what effect the designer is trying to achieve. To flat out say it is poor practice ignores the context of what one is trying to do. Now I might agree that if a designer always designs purely with absolute positioning, then that designer is ignoring the context of the project (since not all sites should be so designed).

Comment: Scott, while absolutely-positioning has its uses, how a project is coded had little to do with the intentions of a designer, it has to do with good coding practices. Absolute positioning of layouts removes a lot of the semantic meaning of a page and can have a negative impact on SEO. It's often a cop-out for solving layout problems with traditional techniques.

Comment: @Diodeus Show me an example of this working with float and remaining liquid and I will surely agree...